# Is it possible to define different css style for a particular webpage

Tags: jquery, css, cakephp

Is there a way to asign css style for a particular webpage. I have tried window.location.href to catch the URL of the page and defined the css but the problem is that page keeps on reloading automatically. I want to define `html` height as `100%` for only one page because the footer for this page is not coming properly as in rest of the pages. Please suggest is it possible to define css style for only single page and if so how to do.

Comment: put this css in your ctp

Comment: if you put the css link in the layout just do another layout, if you are calling it in the view just call a different css... you may use id in your html tag that surrounds that view (you may put a div to help you surround everything) and then use this id to specify how it looks in the css...

Answer (score 1):

So this obviously depends on the application you're writing in Cake, but you can just use a different layout for each page, and include a different stylesheet?

You can just change the `echo $this->Html->css('linktoyourstylesheet');` with conditions.

Comment: See the documentation for the Html Helper at http://api13.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelpercss

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you've structured your site.

If your site is just HTML/CSS then you can simply add a CSS file into that one page's `head` tag:

```
<head>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="/specificpage.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: I am structuring my website using cakephp and not just HTML/CSS

Comment: I've added `cakephp` to your question tags. This should help people to assist you

Answer (score 0):

Give `ID` inside your `body` tag for that specific page & override your css for that specific page write like this:

HTML:

```
<body id="home">
     <div class="main"></div>
   </body>
```

CSS:

```
.main{color:red}

#home .main{color:yellow}
```

Comment: css file cannot be added because it is structured using cakephp which follows mvc architecture. All the pages are linked to the same index.php file which contains the body section. Moreover i want to define the css for html section and not the body, so id or class cannot be used anyway